# {Stuck} Populating Data for Template via Docusign php

Tags: php, soap, docusignapi

I am using SOAP API for DocuSign. It is demo account.

So, I have created my code based on sendatemplate.php and I use the templatereference class to create my FieldData and this is the result in array

```
Array ( [0] => TemplateReference Object ( [TemplateLocation] => Server 
[Template] => 2ade4fe1-9b7b-49eb-af2e-xxxxxxxxx [Document] => 
[RoleAssignments] => Array ( [0] => TemplateReferenceRoleAssignment Object ( 
[RoleName] => Signer1 [RecipientID] => 1 ) ) [FieldData] => 
TemplateReferenceFieldData Object ( [DataValues] => Array ( [0] => 
TemplateReferenceFieldDataDataValue Object ( [TabLabel] => Company [Value] 
=> Otto ) ) ) [AdditionalTabs] => [Sequence] => [TemplateAttachments] => ) )
```

I then use the `RequestStatusResponse` and this is my result:

```
RequestStatusResponse Object
(
    [RequestStatusResult] => EnvelopeStatus Object
        (
            [RecipientStatuses] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [RecipientStatus] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => RecipientStatus Object
                                (
                                    [Type] => Signer
                                    [Email] => xxxxxx@yahoo.com
                                    [UserName] => xxxxx
                                    [RoutingOrder] => 1
                                    [Sent] => 2015-12-02T22:56:01.317
                                    [Delivered] => 2015-12-02T22:56:13.567
                                    [Signed] => 
                                    [Declined] => 
                                    [DeclineReason] => 
                                    [Status] => Delivered
                                    [RecipientIPAddress] => xxxxxxxx
                                    [ClientUserId] => 1
                                    [AutoNavigation] => 
                                    [IDCheckInformation] => 
                                    [RecipientAuthenticationStatus] => 
                                    [CustomFields] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [TabStatuses] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [TabStatus] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => TabStatus Object
                                                        (
                                                            [TabType] => SignHere
                                                            [Status] => Active
                                                            [XPosition] => 1333
                                                            [YPosition] => 964
                                                            [Signed] => 
                                                            [TabLabel] => Signature 1
                                                            [TabName] => Signature
                                                            [TabValue] => 
                                                            [DocumentID] => 
                                                            [PageNumber] => 
                                                            [OriginalValue] => 
                                                            [ValidationPattern] => 
                                                            [RoleName] => 
                                                            [ListValues] => 
                                                            [ListSelectedValue] => 
                                                            [ScaleValue] => 
                                                            [CustomTabType] => 
                                                        )

                                                    [1] => TabStatus Object
                                                        (
                                                            [TabType] => Custom
                                                            [Status] => Active
                                                            [XPosition] => 989
                                                            [YPosition] => 916
                                                            [Signed] => 
                                                            [TabLabel] => Address
                                                            [TabName] => Address
                                                            [TabValue] => 
                                                            [DocumentID] => 
                                                            [PageNumber] => 
                                                            [OriginalValue] => 
                                                            [ValidationPattern] => 
                                                            [RoleName] => 
                                                            [ListValues] => 
                                                            [ListSelectedValue] => 
                                                            [ScaleValue] => 
                                                            [CustomTabType] => 
                                                        )

                                                    [2] => TabStatus Object
                                                        (
                                                            [TabType] => FullName
                                                            [Status] => Active
                                                            [XPosition] => 989
                                                            [YPosition] => 872
                                                            [Signed] => 
                                                            [TabLabel] => Name 1
                                                            [TabName] => Name
                                                            [TabValue] => 
                                                            [DocumentID] => 
                                                            [PageNumber] => 
                                                            [OriginalValue] => 
                                                            [ValidationPattern] => 
                                                            [RoleName] => 
                                                            [ListValues] => 
                                                            [ListSelectedValue] => 
                                                            [ScaleValue] => 
                                                            [CustomTabType] => 
                                                        )

                                                    [3] => TabStatus Object
                                                        (
                                                            [TabType] => Company
                                                            [Status] => Active
                                                            [XPosition] => 683
                                                            [YPosition] => 252
                                                            [Signed] => 
                                                            [TabLabel] => Company
                                                            [TabName] => Company
                                                            [TabValue] => 
                                                            [DocumentID] => 
                                                            [PageNumber] => 
                                                            [OriginalValue] => 
                                                            [ValidationPattern] => 
                                                            [RoleName] => 
                                                            [ListValues] => 
                                                            [ListSelectedValue] => 
                                                            [ScaleValue] => 
                                                            [CustomTabType] => 
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [RecipientAttachment] => 
                                    [AccountStatus] => 
                                    [EsignAgreementInformation] => 
                                    [FormData] => 
                                    [RecipientId] => 
                                )

                        )

                )
```

I don't see my Company values are populated.

Please help!!!

I am using PHP code to do this.